# modify /etc/hosts with shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have lots of /etc/hosts line need to be modify.

Below is example.

original file:

1.1.1.1  A    a
1.1.1.2  B    b
1.1.1.3  C    c
1.1.1.4  D    d
1.1.1.5  E    e
1.1.1.6  F    f
1.1.1.7  G    g

request of modify:
2.1.1.3   B    b
2.1.1.54  E    e
2.1.1.25  G    g

Desired output:
1.1.1.1   A    a
2.1.1.3   B    b
1.1.1.3   C    c
1.1.1.4   D    d
2.1.1.54  E    e
1.1.1.6   F    f
2.1.1.25  G    g

Try to using sed to run, but don't know how to handle more than one line in /etc/hosts.
should I using for loop with sed?

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Please don't multi-post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/727377/133219